# How to get tikzmark to work

Tags: tikzmark

I am having difficulty getting `\tikzmark` to do its magic.  I tried using the tikz library for `\tikzmark` as in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
By taking logarithms of both sides
\[
  t = \frac{30\cdot\ln(3/22)}{\ln(15/22)}
    \tikzmark{calculator}\approx
    156    
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[arrows=->] (calculator) ++(0,2ex) -- (calculator);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I get a complaint as follows:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named calculator is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.14     \draw[arrows=->] (calculator)
                                       ++(0,2ex) -- (calculator);
```

I tried a different approach where I didn't bother to load the `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%,tikzmark}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
By taking logarithms of both sides
\[
  t = \frac{30\cdot\ln(3/22)}{\ln(15/22)}
    \tikzmark{calculator}\approx
    156    
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[arrows=->] (calculator) ++(0,2ex) -- (calculator);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and I get the totally cryptic error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \savepointas
                {calculator}{pgfid1}
?
```

I thought I understood overlays and whatnot, but clearly I don't.

What I would like to do here is something like the following kludge:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%,tikzmark}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
By taking logarithms of both sides
\[
  t = \frac{30\cdot\ln(3/22)}{\ln(15/22)}
    \raisebox{-\height}{$\stackrel{\approx}{\stackrel{\uparrow}{\makebox[0pt]{use calculator}}}$}
    156    
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `tikzmark` library uses the `pic` coordinate system, so you need to call the marks using the `pic cs:` prefix, as in `(pic cs:calculator)`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
By taking logarithms of both sides
\[
  t = \frac{30\cdot\ln(3/22)}{\ln(15/22)}
    \tikzmark{calculator}\approx
    156    
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[arrows=->] 
    ( $ (pic cs:calculator) +(6pt,-2.5ex) $ ) -- 
    ( $ (pic cs:calculator) +(6pt,-0.5ex) $ );
    \node[anchor=north]
    at ( $ (pic cs:calculator) +(6pt,-2ex) $ )
    {Use calculator};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With your second code, the problem is that in the first run, the coordinates for the mark mark are still not calculated. The second run of the code works since by then the coordinate has been appropriately calculated and the arrow can be drawn. You can avoid the error in the first run by using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%,tikzmark}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\begin{document}
By taking logarithms of both sides
\[
  t = \frac{30\cdot\ln(3/22)}{\ln(15/22)}
    \tikzmark{calculator}\approx
    156    
\]
\expandafter \ifx\csname pgf@sys@pdf@mark@pos@pgfid\the \csname
pgf@picture@serial@count\endcsname\endcsname\relax
\else
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[arrows=->] 
  ( $ (calculator) +(6pt,-2.5ex) $ ) -- 
  ( $ (calculator) +(6pt,-0.5ex) $ );
\node[anchor=north]
  at ( $ (calculator) +(6pt,-2ex) $ )
  {Use calculator};\end{tikzpicture}
\fi
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I get the arrow under the `\approx`?

Comment: Also, I wanted to do somehting more like `\draw[arrows=->] (pic cs:calculator) ++ (0,-4ex) -- (pic cs:calculator.south);`.  But, `.south` gets placed completely incorrectly.

Comment: @A.Ellett Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @A.Ellett I don't think you can use `.south` because pics do not have anchors in the same way that nodes do. (Unless the `tikzmark` library does the work to emulate them?)

Comment: Is there a way to get my second code to work without it generating an error on the first run (I understand that the node will not be place correctly until the second run)?

Comment: @A.Ellett yes, there is. Give me some seconds and I will add this to my answer. Regarding the `.south` operation, take into account that using `\tikzmark` doesn't really produce a node, so those modifiers won't work.

Comment: @A.Ellett I added the code that will prevent the error in the first run using your second code.

Comment: You are correct about the new code not generating an error.  I'm not sure what that code's actually doing.  But the expansion text seems to fail for every run and the tikzpicture is never drawn.

Comment: @A.Ellett Hmmmm. Let me think about this.

Comment: @A.Ellett Please see my updated answer (I had forgotten the required `\else` so the drawing is made after the first run and the closing `\fi`).

Answer (score 12):

For fun, a variant without `tikz` and without the need for an additional LaTeX run:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
By taking logarithms of both sides
\[
  t = \frac{30\cdot\ln(3/22)}{\ln(15/22)}
  \underset{\mathclap{\shortstack{$\uparrow$\\[-.2ex]use calculator}}
  }{\approx} 156
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- Package `mathtools` loads `amsmath` and defines further commands like `\mathclap`, in this case also `\makebox[0pt]{...}` can be used.
- `\underset` comes from package `amsmath`.
- `\shortstack` is defined in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: So much better than my kludge.  Thank you for this post and reminding me about the `mathtools` package.

Answer (score 2):

A variation which just creates a coordinate underneath the `\approx` sign, picking up the horizontal distance from two marks and adjusting the vertical somewhat. This coordinate is then used as the basis for placing the node and arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
By taking logarithms of both sides
\[
  t = \frac{30\cdot\ln(3/22)}{\ln(15/22)}
  \tikzmark{calculator}\approx\tikzmark{otherside}
    156
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \coordinate (target) at ($(pic cs:calculator)!1/2!(pic cs:otherside) - (0,.5ex)$);
  \draw[arrows=->] (target) ++(0,-2ex) node [anchor=north] {use calculator} -- (target);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: marks and coordinates]

Comment: Very nice approach to centering the arrow below the `\approx`.

Comment: @A.Ellett Thanks. I'm not sure if it is efficient, but I often find this is the simplest way to centre something in TiKZ ;). (And since you were loading `calc` anyway, I figured calculating the extra coordinate couldn't hurt much.)