# How to create this diagram(equation with labels) with Tikz?

Tags: diagrams

I'm not sure how to create the following diagram with Tikz

I thought of using nodes, but I'm not sure how we would go about it...

[image]

Comment: This is not too hard to do. But as it sits here your question is more of the type `please do this for me` which is disliked here as this is a Q'n'A site not a "sweatshop", you should at least show some initiative and provide something others can work with.. You can probably mess about with this answer using `tikzmark`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209052/how-to-get-tikzmark-to-work

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the info. I'll check tikzmark. (I didn't know it existed even...)

Comment: Is it necessary to realize your image with TikZ?

Comment: @Sebastiano no it's not. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something to get started in the right direction --adapted from

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/global-nodes/

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% For every picture that defines or uses external nodes, you'll have to
% apply the 'remember picture' style. To avoid some typing, we'll apply
% the style to all pictures

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

% By default all math in TikZ nodes are set in inline mode. Change this to
% displaystyle so that we don't get small fractions

\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Physical Experiment Response
        \tikz\node [fill=blue!20,draw,circle] (n1) {};
\end{itemize}

% Below we mix an ordinary equation with TikZ nodes. Note that we have to
% adjust the baseline of the nodes to get proper alignment with the rest of
% the equation

\begin{equation}
            \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t1)
            {$y^e(x)$};
        } 
        =
        \tikz[baseline]{
            \node[fill=red!20,anchor=base] (t2)
            {$y^m(x,\theta^*)$};
        } 
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Computer Model Response
        \tikz\node [fill=red!20,draw,circle] (n2) {};
\end{itemize}

% Now it's time to draw some edges between the global nodes. Note that we
% have to apply the 'overlay' style

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->] (n1) edge [bend left] (t1);
        \path[->] (n2) edge [bend right] (t2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```