# Remarks in equations with arrows

Tags: equations, tikz-arrows, arrows, annotations

In huge calculations it's often very helpful as reader to have nice remarks about which manipulation was made. Also, other remarks in equations can help alot, e.g., this one

[image]

which I like more than the ^-convention.
I am generating the above with the following code

```
\vertarrowbox{e_j}{$i$\textsuperscript{th} spot}
```

where

```
\newcommand\vertarrowbox[3][2ex]{%
    \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}} #2 \\[-0.7ex]
        \left\uparrow\vcenter{\hrule height #1}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\\[-1.2ex]
        \makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize#3}
    \end{array}%
}
```

My goal now is to achieve something similar. I am looking for something like this

[image]

to denote that the exchange of the two variables gives a minus sign.

I wonder how I could implement this. I am not sure if tikz-cd is the way to go (I don't have experience with tikz-cd in equations like this and don't know if it is even possible to use it this way).

Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: I would use plain `tikz` and the `tikzmark` library, see for example  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209056/3929

Comment: @daleif Thank you very much! Please see my own answer. Maybe you can help me further.

Answer (score 2):

After @daleif gave me the tip to use tikz and tikzmark I found how to do it with some trial and error (tikz seems super complex and powerful). **Please** correct or improve this solution (I am not fully aware of every comment and if this could be done more nicely of if I am doing something very stupid here).

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{equation*}
    f(\tikzmarknode{a}a,b,c,d,\tikzmarknode{e}e) = -f(e,b,c,d,a)
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw [>=latex,<->]
    (a.south) to[out=-90,in=-90,looseness=1] node [below,sloped] (TextNode1) 
    {\scriptsize$\cdot (-1)$} (e.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

yields

[image]

**However** two problems remain:

1. I want to apply this in an align environment. But then the spacing is messed up:

   ```
    \begin{align*}
         f(a,b,c,d,e) &= f(\tikzmarknode{a}a,b,c,d,\tikzmarknode{e}e) \\
                      &= -f(e,b,c,d,a)
    \end{align*}
   ```

[image]

2. As I will use this very often in the document, I want to write a command for it. But how could I implement that? The obvious problem is that the \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] thing has to come *after* the whole align environment and I have only ever worked with commands which "replace in place".

Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT:
I added a brace underneath to better symbolize what term exactly is moved. Also read my comment under this answer.
[image]

Comment: I decided that it was a huge overkill to write a command for this. My knowledge in LaTeX is way too bad for that. Imagine I wanted to use the command twice in one align environment. Many problems come up.
Instead, I will just use my first approach as above in every single case and maybe give more vertical space after the \\ in the align enviroment by hand.

Comment: may be you should  increase the vertical spacing in the align block to fix the text overlap .  `\begin{align*}
      f(a,b,c,d,e) &= f(\tikzmarknode{a}a,b,c,d,\tikzmarknode{e}e) \\[2cm]
                   &= -f(e,b,c,d,a)
 \end{align*}`

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Yes, that's what I am doing now. It's not nice that way, but it works. Thanks!